# To sed match and some text in newlines

Tags: text-processing, sed

You want to visualize maximum 10 marks but minimum 1 mark after the sequence `65 72 62 65` in a newline where the dummy data source is `hexdump -v /usr/bin/telnet` and the `less` is a viewer.
Code

```
hexdump -v /usr/bin/telnet                        \
  | sed 's/65 72 62 65[a-z0-9]\{1,10\}/&...\n/g'  \
                                                  \
  | less -s -M +Gg
```

The unsuccessful output is the following containing the start of the input while it should start from the the first match and contain only a few characters after it until the next match in a newline

```
0000000 cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01 03 00 00 80 02 00 00 00
...
```

Wanted output

```
65 72 62 65 000edf0 72 ...
65 72 62 65 72 6f 73 20 56 ...
65 72 62 65 72 6f 73 20 56 ...
...
```

How can you visualize only matches and some text after them in newlines?

Comment: So what's your input? Don't assume that we get the same output for `hexdump -v /usr/bin/telnet` as you do. For example, on my system, `hexdump -v /usr/bin/telnet | grep "65 72 62 65"` returns nothing. Are you just looking for `sed 's/.*\(65 72 62 65 [a-z0-9]\{1,10\}\).*/\1...\n/g'`?

Comment: Just the verbose hexdump of telnet. You can use any sequence for matching.

Comment: Yes, I know, I can see that. My version of `telnet` doesn't contain the string you are looking for. Since, presumably, you don't actually care about `telnet`, why don't you give us an example input and the output you would like to see from it? Also, did you try my sed command?

Comment: @terdon I think you may have the correct solution! I forgor the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print only the matched portion of a string, you can use one of match everything before and after the desired string and replace it with the string:

```
 sed 's/.*\(65 72 62 65 .\{1,10\}\).*/\1.../'
```

Comment: This does one of everything after the last string in pattern space which looks like the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n 's/65 72 62 65[[:hexdigit:] ]\{1,10\}/&...\n/;/\n/P'
```

You were almost there. You just needed to `P`rint it differently. That command will print from the head of the line up to just beyond the first match on a line for the string specified. If you want to go the other way round, and print just from the head of the first match to the end of a line...

```
    sed '/\n/P;//d;s/65 72 62 65[[:hexdigit:] ]\{1,10\}/\n&...\n/;D'
```

...that will work.